# Why has pip3 install multiprocessing failed in Windows subsystem for Linux?

Tags: python, pip, multiprocessing, windows-subsystem-for-linux

I'm relatively new to Linux, and I need to install Python's multiprocessing library so I can run some Python scripts I've written and compare the results of parallel vs sequential simulations.

I've got python version 3 and pip3 installed on Windows subsystem for Linux and tried to execute the following line to install the multiprocessing library:

```
pip3 install multiprocessing
```

This command worked when installing numpy and scipy. Trying to do it with multiprocessing raises the following error which is in the screenshot.

[image]

I don't understand where or what my problem is, any suggestions?

Cheers

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Python 3 has the `multiprocessing` module built in. You do not need to install it from pip. You can just `import multiprocessing` and use it.

What happens here is that pip tries to install the Python 2 version, because back then, `multiprocessing` was a third-party package.

Answer (score 1):

The [multiprocessing](https://pypi.org/project/multiprocessing/) that `pip` can find on PyPI is a back-port intended to provide the functionality on Python 2.x. Because it's Python 2.x code, the `setup.py` in the installer is written for Python 2.x as well, and in particular it uses the `print` statement that is not valid in 3.x (since `print` is now a function).

In 3.x, `multiprocessing` is *part of the standard library*, so the correct way to install it is to do nothing.